# How slice operator workd internally to prevent side effect while copyting variables

Tags: python, list

I read this article - http://www.python-course.eu/deep_copy.php. But I could not understand how internally [:] works to prevent the side effect or I should take it as it is the compiler feature. ?

Comment: Prevent what side effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slices in Python use copies of data, rather than the original data.

Using `x = y[:]` makes an actual copy, rather than just assigning a reference. A slice in Python is a separate copy of the data, and a `[:]` slice is one that contains the entire set of data being sliced.

So `x = y` just says "make x point to the same sequence as y" but `x = y[:]` says "make x point to a copy of all of the data in the sequence that y points to."